# Average payout of mined bucket?

Tags: wallet

What is the average payout of mined btc from blockchain to blockchain wallets?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're asking? Average payout per what?

Answer (score 1):

The block reward for successfully mining a block is currently 12.5 BTC.

By participating in a mining pool the group has a significantly higher chance as a whole of solving a block. Rewards are then shared based on a formula. It can be suggested, though it is not always the only factor in the formula for a mining pool, that your individual hash rate as a share of the pool total hash rate determines your share percentage.